# Play routes: route assets in different folders into separate paths

Tags: playframework, routes, swagger-ui

I've developed a simple Play application that uses AngularJS as frontend, and SwaggerUI as a convenient frontend to test Play's endpoints. The project structure of the generated frontend assets looks like the following:

```
prj/build
      +- ui
      |  +- dist
      |    +- <compiled typescript assets into js files> 
      |    +- index.html (which include above js files with relative path)
      +- swagger-ui
      |    +- <swagger-ui.js etc...> 
      |    +- index.html (which include above js files with relative path)
```

What I would like to achieve, is to:

- route the main app's UI, `ui/dist/index.html`, to `localhost/`
- route the app's swagger UI, `swagger-ui/index.html`, to `localhost/api`

However, the Play routes setup is giving me an headache: if I setup just one of the two (either `/` or `/api`), it works. For example

```
GET        /api          controllers.Assets.at(path = "/swagger-ui", file = "index.html")
GET        /*file        controllers.Assets.at(path = "/swagger-ui", file)
```

is fine, and I can see swagger UI; if I try to combine all of them together like this though

```
GET        /             controllers.Assets.at(path = "/ui/dist", file = "index.html")
GET        /*file        controllers.Assets.at(path = "/ui/dist", file) # (1)
GET        /api          controllers.Assets.at(path = "/swagger-ui", file = "index.html")
GET        /api/*file    controllers.Assets.at(path = "/swagger-ui", file)
```

the regular app works, but I'll get an `Action Not Found` from Play when I try to access `/api` because `(1)` takes precedence; no matter how I shuffle the assets routes, or tinker with their parameters, I can't seem to be able to make them both worth, due to how `Assets.at(...)` works.

The closest I solution I came up with, was to [override the default SwaggerUI index.html](https://github.com/int128/gradle-swagger-generator-plugin#configure-swagger-ui), and prepend every js resource path with the `swagger-ui/` prefix; this way, both the main app UI and swagger ui work, but it feels sort of hackish.

Is there a way to properly achieve that, using proper Play routes syntax? or perhaps defining two Assets controllers, one for the main app, and one for swagger-ui?

Thanks!